# How to switch a register to a login form (or other way round) with a link within one jsp?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am a beginner in java development and learning Spring MVC recently. I am required to create a Register and Login page in one jsp only. Below is what I did so far in my body.

```
<sf:form action="register" method="POST" modelAttribute="user">
    <sf:input path="username" placeholder="Username" type="text"/>
    <sf:input path="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</sf:form>

<sf:form action="login" method="POST" modelAttribute="user">
    <sf:input path="username" placeholder="Username" type="text"/>
    <sf:input path="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
</sf:form>
```

How could I switch the form with a link and then a click it, the form will change?

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch your submit button to hyper link & use ajax to send post request to servlet. See below for example (**untested code**)

```
<sf:form action="register" method="POST" modelAttribute="user">
 <sf:input id="userName" path="username" placeholder="Username" type="text"/>
 <sf:input id="password" path="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
 <a id="submit">submit</a>
</sf:form>

<Script>
   $("#submit").click(function(){
      var uName = $("#userName).val();
      var pwd= $("#password).val();
      $.post( 
             "register", 
             { userName: uName, password: pwd } 
            );
   });
</script>
```